# AddOpenIdConnect with Azure AD V2

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

Having some issues with AddOpenIdConnect in net core 2.0 and Azure AD (V2). After challenging, entering credentials in Azure AD and being returned back to my application the authenticationhandler seems to redirect me to the original method that initiated the challenge rather than the defined callback method.
However, the httpcontext.user is populated with a claims identity with the correct claims on it.

Code is simplified for the purpose of this post.

Startup looks like:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = "aad";
                o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
            {
                if (!Environment.IsProduction())
                {
                    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                }
                o.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Authority");
                o.Audience = Constants.Audiences.Self;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
                    RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role,
                    IssuerSigningKey =
                        new X509SecurityKey(
                            GetSigningCertificate(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Certificates:Signing")))
                };
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", o =>
            {
                if (!Environment.IsProduction())
                {
                    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                }
                o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/v2.0";
                o.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
                o.ClientId = "[clientid]";
                o.ClientSecret = "[clientsecret]";
                o.ResponseMode = "form_post";
                o.ResponseType = "id_token";
                o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/api/connect/microsoftcallback2");
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/v2.0"
                };
            });
```

Challenge:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("authorize", Name = "authorize")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChallengeTemp()
    {
        return Challenge("aad");
    }
```

Trace log:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44301/api/connect/microsoftcallback2 application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1771
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44301/api/connect/microsoftcallback2 application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1771
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Trace: Entering Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler's HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Trace: Entering Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler's HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Debug: Connection id "0HLC9LOBLM019", Request id "0HLC9LOBLM019:00000004": started reading request body.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Debug: Connection id "0HLC9LOBLM019", Request id "0HLC9LOBLM019:00000004": started reading request body.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Debug: Connection id "0HLC9LOBLM019", Request id "0HLC9LOBLM019:00000004": done reading request body.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Debug: Connection id "0HLC9LOBLM019", Request id "0HLC9LOBLM019:00000004": done reading request body.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', 'aad', 'v1').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', 'aad', 'v1').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Trace: MessageReceived: '?id_token={keyremoved}'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Trace: MessageReceived: '?id_token={keyremoved}'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Debug: Updating configuration
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Debug: Updating configuration
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Debug: Received 'id_token'
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Debug: Received 'id_token'
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', 'System.String', 'aad', 'v1').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler', 'System.String', 'aad', 'v1').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing protect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Cookies', 'v2').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing protect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Cookies', 'v2').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Debug: Connection id "0HLC9LOBLM019" completed keep alive response.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Debug: Connection id "0HLC9LOBLM019" completed keep alive response.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 129.6921ms 302 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 129.6921ms 302 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44301/api/connect/authorize
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44301/api/connect/authorize
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Cookies', 'v2').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector:Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {keyremoved} with purposes ('workspace', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Cookies', 'v2').
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter:Debug: Request successfully matched the route with name 'authorize' and template 'api/connect/authorize'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter:Debug: Request successfully matched the route with name 'authorize' and template 'api/connect/authorize'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your log carefully, you'll see that it says this:

> Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:44301/api/connect/microsoftcallback2

Since you specified the response should come as a POST with:

```
o.ResponseMode = "form_post";
```

You get the response as a POST in the callback you defined.

Now by default the OIDC handler will redirect you back to the path you were trying to access when the challenge was issued. You can see the 302 redirect in the log too.

In the case of an explicit login handler, that is not good.
You should define it yourself with:

```
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = "/"
}, "aad");
```

In this case the user will be redirected to the root of the app after the login is processed.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed the callbackpath defined would be used by the handler for redirection, but I now see it only seems to be used for the handler to listen on requests and I need to send it with the challenge. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the callback path is used as the URL for the response from AAD. The redirect here is the "local redirect URL" that is used after auth is done.

Comment: You saved me after googling for over 2 days. Thank you!!